# JQuery image.mapster with other jquery version clash

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am facing some jquery conflict between image.mapster jquery to hover custom div in image and other jquery versions used to zoom out and zoom in on button click.

Below are the query which i am facing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
```

If i write the code in above sequence, `image.mapster` jquery will work on hover but my zoom in and zoom out functionality will not work.

and if i use the `image.mapster` query first then write the second jquery then i gets the error as method `image.mapster` not found.

I have created a test file code also 
http://jsfiddle.net/vpd1Lbtp/3/
 but in jsfidder it works partially both things works but size of image is not getting zoom in and out.also i write the same in html code only one functionality works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect `img#vegetables` while zooming you will see your code to scale it is actually running. However, Mapster has set the opacity of the image to 0. The image you're looking at is the one created by Mapster with `class="mapster_el"`.

I think you can get the functionality you want by scaling `.mapster_el` instead of `#vegetables`:

```
$('.mapster_el').stop(true, true).animate({
//etc...
```

This will scale the copied image along with the `canvas` elements representing the map.